# Blocking on DBCP connection pool (open and close connection). Is database connection pooling in OpenEJB pluggable?

Tags: java, transactions, connection-pooling, blocking, openejb

We use OpenEJB on Tomcat (used to run on JBoss, Weblogic, etc.). While running load tests we experience significant performance problems with handling JMS messages (queues). Problem was localized to blocking on database connection pool getting or releasing connection to the pool. Blocking prevented concurrent MDB instances (threads) from running hence performance suffered 10-fold and worse. The same code used to run on application servers (with their respective connection pool implementations) with no blocking at all.

Example of thread blocked:

```
Name: JMS Resource Adapter-worker-23
State: BLOCKED on org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool@1ea6b4a owned by: JMS Resource Adapter-worker-19
Total blocked: 18,426  Total waited: 0

Stack trace: 
org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.returnObject(GenericObjectPool.java:916)
org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnection.close(PoolableConnection.java:91)
   - locked org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnection@1bcba8
org.apache.commons.dbcp.managed.ManagedConnection.close(ManagedConnection.java:147)
com.xxxxx.persistence.DbHelper.closeConnection(DbHelper.java:290)
....
```

Couple of questions.

1. I am almost certain that some transactional attributes and properties contribute to this blocking, but MDBs are defined as non-transactional (we use both annotations and ejb-jar.xml). Some EJBs do use container-managed transactions though (and we can observe blocking there as well). Are there any DBCP configurations that may fix blocking?
2. Is DBCP connection pool implementation replaceable in OpenEJB? How easy (difficult) to replace it with another library?

Just in case this is how we define data source in OpenEJB (openejb.xml):

```
<Resource id="MyDataSource" type="DataSource">
  JdbcDriver oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
  JdbcUrl ${oracle.jdbc}
  UserName ${oracle.user}
  Password ${oracle.password}
  JtaManaged true
  InitialSize 5
  MaxActive 30
  ValidationQuery SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
  TestOnBorrow true
</Resource>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved issue with dbcp blocking by changing pool configuration (*openejb.xml*):

`TestOnBorrow false`

Thank you, [Andy](http://openejb.979440.n4.nabble.com/DBCP-Connection-pool-blocks-threads-on-open-close-connections-tc3303674.html), from OpenEJB team!

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cts...

> 1 - Are there any DBCP configurations that
>   may fix blocking?

Although I cannot see it in the doc, I think there should also be a setting attribute named 'WhenExaustedAction' in the Resource node that could take a value "GROW" (value 2) as opposed to "BLOCK" (value 1) or "FAIL" (value 0).  This comes straight from the Pools common.
Both Hibernate and Cayenne do use this DBCP setting.  Don't know about OpenEJB though.

No need to say that this would work only if all connections are dutifully closed of course (which is sometimes hard to guarantee).
Then you could probably see through JMX how many connections you need at peak activity time and you could then set the maxActive to a higher value evolved from these measures.

> 2 - Is DBCP connection pool implementation
>   replaceable in OpenEJB? How easy
>   (difficult) to replace it with another
>   library?

Sorry no idea.  Would imagine yes.  Or possibly DBCP allows another connection pool manager.

UPDATE: Just had a look in the code and it seems DBCP is the only option for connection pooling.

Incidentally I've seen that the whenExhaustedAction settings. is not supported by openejb.xml.
There would however, still be one option left, since you are using an Oracle Database.
One thing you could try is to use Oracle implicit connection caching (assuming version 10g) and leave DBCP with an arbitrary "sufficient" amount of connections.
To do so, you would need to configure in the openejb.xml resource block, `ConnectionProperties` properties and use Oracle JDBC connection properties.  That is `connectionCachingEnabled=true` and at least `connectionCacheName` and `connectionCacheProperties`.  In this way I would lure DBCP into believing it's doing the real job and actually using Oracle's pooling mechanism.  That would also mean taking little risks with DBCP and thereby a more liberal sizing of the maxActive setting.

Comment: Thanks, Alain. Part of the mystery that blocking occurs on returning connections back to the pool. 'WhenExhaustedAction' is for retrieving connections. Any idea what configuration I need to activate JMX access to DBCP pools? So far, in JMX console under openejb we can see only EJB pools.

Comment: I have no idea why returning the connection should block... As for JMX, I do not think DBCP has a JMX adapter (need to check).  I was more thinking of the oracle JMX instrumentation included in their jdbc driver.  In addition, since I wrote this answer a few days ago, I realized that standard DBCP does not support the whenExhaustedAction setting.  I planned to have a look into cayenne and hibernate source code to find out how they added it and never came around doing it.  However, a more direct path to the solution would be to boost the maxActive setting... see next comment ;-)

Comment: ... (follow up ;-)  Providing the setting is not ignored... (default is 10)...  If a massive increase of maxActive gets rid of the pb, one can then think the pb is just about tuning the right config.

Comment: posted on OpenEJB forum and got this issue resolved by simple configuration change in dbcp: http://openejb.979440.n4.nabble.com/DBCP-Connection-pool-blocks-threads-on-open-close-connections-tc3303674.html

Comment: thx for updating me. I read the explanations from Andy and that makes sense.  In the end your initial gut feeling of 'DBCP connection pool implementation replaceable in OpenEJB ?' still stands as pertinent as ever.